# Compilation error (Missing Library) under Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino

I have been trying to compile a code for a accelerometer which is avaiable from two sources but referring to the same code on github:

https://github.com/ayildirim/OpenVR

https://github.com/ptrbrtz/razor-9dof-ahrs/

Both of this sources contain the following arduino code(c++):

```
#define HW__VERSION_CODE 10736 // SparkFun "9DOF Razor IMU" version "SEN-10736" (HMC5883L magnetometer)


// OUTPUT OPTIONS
/*****************************************************************/
// Set your serial port baud rate used to send out data here!
#define OUTPUT__BAUD_RATE 57600

// Sensor data output interval in milliseconds
// This may not work, if faster than 20ms (=50Hz)
// Code is tuned for 20ms, so better leave it like that
#define OUTPUT__DATA_INTERVAL 20  // in milliseconds

// Output mode definitions (do not change)
#define OUTPUT__MODE_CALIBRATE_SENSORS 0 // Outputs sensor min/max values as text for manual calibration
#define OUTPUT__MODE_ANGLES 1 // Outputs yaw/pitch/roll in degrees
#define OUTPUT__MODE_SENSORS_CALIB 2 // Outputs calibrated sensor values for all 9 axes
#define OUTPUT__MODE_SENSORS_RAW 3 // Outputs raw (uncalibrated) sensor values for all 9 axes
#define OUTPUT__MODE_SENSORS_BOTH 4 // Outputs calibrated AND raw sensor values for all 9 axes
// Output format definitions (do not change)
#define OUTPUT__FORMAT_TEXT 0 // Outputs data as text
#define OUTPUT__FORMAT_BINARY 1 // Outputs data as binary float

// Select your startup output mode and format here!
int output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_ANGLES;
int output_format = OUTPUT__FORMAT_TEXT;

// Select if serial continuous streaming output is enabled per default on startup.
#define OUTPUT__STARTUP_STREAM_ON true  // true or false

// If set true, an error message will be output if we fail to read sensor data.
// Message format: "!ERR: reading <sensor>", followed by "\r\n".
boolean output_errors = false;  // true or false

// Bluetooth
// You can set this to true, if you have a Rovering Networks Bluetooth Module attached.
// The connect/disconnect message prefix of the module has to be set to "#".
// (Refer to manual, it can be set like this: SO,#)
// When using this, streaming output will only be enabled as long as we're connected. That way
// receiver and sender are synchronzed easily just by connecting/disconnecting.
// It is not necessary to set this! It just makes life easier when writing code for
// the receiving side. The Processing test sketch also works without setting this.
// NOTE: When using this, OUTPUT__STARTUP_STREAM_ON has no effect!
#define OUTPUT__HAS_RN_BLUETOOTH false  // true or false


// SENSOR CALIBRATION
/*****************************************************************/
// How to calibrate? Read the tutorial at http://dev.qu.tu-berlin.de/projects/sf-razor-9dof-ahrs
// Put MIN/MAX and OFFSET readings for your board here!
// Accelerometer
// "accel x,y,z (min/max) = X_MIN/X_MAX  Y_MIN/Y_MAX  Z_MIN/Z_MAX"
#define ACCEL_X_MIN ((float) -289)
#define ACCEL_X_MAX ((float) 294)
#define ACCEL_Y_MIN ((float) -268)
#define ACCEL_Y_MAX ((float) 288)
#define ACCEL_Z_MIN ((float) -294)
#define ACCEL_Z_MAX ((float) 269)

// Magnetometer (standard calibration)
// "magn x,y,z (min/max) = X_MIN/X_MAX  Y_MIN/Y_MAX  Z_MIN/Z_MAX"
//#define MAGN_X_MIN ((float) -600)
//#define MAGN_X_MAX ((float) 600)
//#define MAGN_Y_MIN ((float) -600)
//#define MAGN_Y_MAX ((float) 600)
//#define MAGN_Z_MIN ((float) -600)
//#define MAGN_Z_MAX ((float) 600)

// Magnetometer (extended calibration)
// Uncommend to use extended magnetometer calibration (compensates hard & soft iron errors)
#define CALIBRATION__MAGN_USE_EXTENDED true
const float magn_ellipsoid_center[3] = {
  3.80526, -16.4455, 87.4052};
const float magn_ellipsoid_transform[3][3] = {
  {
    0.970991, 0.00583310, -0.00265756                              }
  , {
    0.00583310, 0.952958, 2.76726e-05                              }
  , {
    -0.00265756, 2.76726e-05, 0.999751                              }
};
// Gyroscope
// "gyro x,y,z (current/average) = .../OFFSET_X  .../OFFSET_Y  .../OFFSET_Z
#define GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_X ((float) 23.85)
#define GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_Y ((float) -53.41)
#define GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_Z ((float) -15.32)

/*
// Calibration example:

 // "accel x,y,z (min/max) = -278.00/270.00  -254.00/284.00  -294.00/235.00"
 #define ACCEL_X_MIN ((float) -278)
 #define ACCEL_X_MAX ((float) 270)
 #define ACCEL_Y_MIN ((float) -254)
 #define ACCEL_Y_MAX ((float) 284)
 #define ACCEL_Z_MIN ((float) -294)
 #define ACCEL_Z_MAX ((float) 235)

 // "magn x,y,z (min/max) = -511.00/581.00  -516.00/568.00  -489.00/486.00"
 //#define MAGN_X_MIN ((float) -511)
 //#define MAGN_X_MAX ((float) 581)
 //#define MAGN_Y_MIN ((float) -516)
 //#define MAGN_Y_MAX ((float) 568)
 //#define MAGN_Z_MIN ((float) -489)
 //#define MAGN_Z_MAX ((float) 486)

 // Extended magn
 #define CALIBRATION__MAGN_USE_EXTENDED true
 const float magn_ellipsoid_center[3] = {91.5, -13.5, -48.1};
 const float magn_ellipsoid_transform[3][3] = {{0.902, -0.00354, 0.000636}, {-0.00354, 0.9, -0.00599}, {0.000636, -0.00599, 1}};

 // Extended magn (with Sennheiser HD 485 headphones)
 //#define CALIBRATION__MAGN_USE_EXTENDED true
 //const float magn_ellipsoid_center[3] = {72.3360, 23.0954, 53.6261};
 //const float magn_ellipsoid_transform[3][3] = {{0.879685, 0.000540833, -0.0106054}, {0.000540833, 0.891086, -0.0130338}, {-0.0106054, -0.0130338, 0.997494}};

 //"gyro x,y,z (current/average) = -32.00/-34.82  102.00/100.41  -16.00/-16.38"
 #define GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_X ((float) -34.82)
 #define GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_Y ((float) 100.41)
 #define GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_Z ((float) -16.38)
 */


// DEBUG OPTIONS
/*****************************************************************/
// When set to true, gyro drift correction will not be applied
#define DEBUG__NO_DRIFT_CORRECTION false
// Print elapsed time after each I/O loop
#define DEBUG__PRINT_LOOP_TIME false


/*****************************************************************/
/****************** END OF USER SETUP AREA!  *********************/
/*****************************************************************/










// Check if hardware version code is defined
#ifndef HW__VERSION_CODE
// Generate compile error
#error YOU HAVE TO SELECT THE HARDWARE YOU ARE USING! See "HARDWARE OPTIONS" in "USER SETUP AREA" at top of Razor_AHRS.pde (or .ino)!
#endif

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Compass.h>
#include <DCM.h>
#include <Math.h>
#include <Output.h>
#include <Sensors.h>
// Sensor calibration scale and offset values
#define ACCEL_X_OFFSET ((ACCEL_X_MIN + ACCEL_X_MAX) / 2.0f)
#define ACCEL_Y_OFFSET ((ACCEL_Y_MIN + ACCEL_Y_MAX) / 2.0f)
#define ACCEL_Z_OFFSET ((ACCEL_Z_MIN + ACCEL_Z_MAX) / 2.0f)
#define ACCEL_X_SCALE (GRAVITY / (ACCEL_X_MAX - ACCEL_X_OFFSET))
#define ACCEL_Y_SCALE (GRAVITY / (ACCEL_Y_MAX - ACCEL_Y_OFFSET))
#define ACCEL_Z_SCALE (GRAVITY / (ACCEL_Z_MAX - ACCEL_Z_OFFSET))

#define MAGN_X_OFFSET ((MAGN_X_MIN + MAGN_X_MAX) / 2.0f)
#define MAGN_Y_OFFSET ((MAGN_Y_MIN + MAGN_Y_MAX) / 2.0f)
#define MAGN_Z_OFFSET ((MAGN_Z_MIN + MAGN_Z_MAX) / 2.0f)
#define MAGN_X_SCALE (100.0f / (MAGN_X_MAX - MAGN_X_OFFSET))
#define MAGN_Y_SCALE (100.0f / (MAGN_Y_MAX - MAGN_Y_OFFSET))
#define MAGN_Z_SCALE (100.0f / (MAGN_Z_MAX - MAGN_Z_OFFSET))


// Gain for gyroscope (ITG-3200)
#define GYRO_GAIN 0.06957 // Same gain on all axes
#define GYRO_SCALED_RAD(x) (x * TO_RAD(GYRO_GAIN)) // Calculate the scaled gyro readings in radians per second

// DCM parameters
#define Kp_ROLLPITCH 0.02f
#define Ki_ROLLPITCH 0.00002f
#define Kp_YAW 1.2f
#define Ki_YAW 0.00002f

// Stuff
#define STATUS_LED_PIN 13  // Pin number of status LED
#define GRAVITY 256.0f // "1G reference" used for DCM filter and accelerometer calibration
#define TO_RAD(x) (x * 0.01745329252)  // *pi/180
#define TO_DEG(x) (x * 57.2957795131)  // *180/pi

// Sensor variables
float accel[3];  // Actually stores the NEGATED acceleration (equals gravity, if board not moving).
float accel_min[3];
float accel_max[3];

float magnetom[3];
float magnetom_min[3];
float magnetom_max[3];
float magnetom_tmp[3];

float gyro[3];
float gyro_average[3];
int gyro_num_samples = 0;

// DCM variables
float MAG_Heading;
float Accel_Vector[3]= {
  0, 0, 0}; // Store the acceleration in a vector
float Gyro_Vector[3]= {
  0, 0, 0}; // Store the gyros turn rate in a vector
float Omega_Vector[3]= {
  0, 0, 0}; // Corrected Gyro_Vector data
float Omega_P[3]= {
  0, 0, 0}; // Omega Proportional correction
float Omega_I[3]= {
  0, 0, 0}; // Omega Integrator
float Omega[3]= {
  0, 0, 0};
float errorRollPitch[3] = {
  0, 0, 0};
float errorYaw[3] = {
  0, 0, 0};
float DCM_Matrix[3][3] = {
  {
    1, 0, 0                              }
  , {
    0, 1, 0                              }
  , {
    0, 0, 1                              }
};
float Update_Matrix[3][3] = {
  {
    0, 1, 2                              }
  , {
    3, 4, 5                              }
  , {
    6, 7, 8                              }
};
float Temporary_Matrix[3][3] = {
  {
    0, 0, 0                              }
  , {
    0, 0, 0                              }
  , {
    0, 0, 0                              }
};

// Euler angles
float yaw;
float pitch;
float roll;

// DCM timing in the main loop
unsigned long timestamp;
unsigned long timestamp_old;
float G_Dt; // Integration time for DCM algorithm

// More output-state variables
boolean output_stream_on;
boolean output_single_on;
int curr_calibration_sensor = 0;
boolean reset_calibration_session_flag = true;
int num_accel_errors = 0;
int num_magn_errors = 0;
int num_gyro_errors = 0;

void read_sensors() {
  Read_Gyro(); // Read gyroscope
  Read_Accel(); // Read accelerometer
  Read_Magn(); // Read magnetometer
}

// Read every sensor and record a time stamp
// Init DCM with unfiltered orientation
// TODO re-init global vars?
void reset_sensor_fusion() {
  float temp1[3];
  float temp2[3];
  float xAxis[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f                              };

  read_sensors();
  timestamp = millis();

  // GET PITCH
  // Using y-z-plane-component/x-component of gravity vector
  pitch = -atan2(accel[0], sqrt(accel[1] * accel[1] + accel[2] * accel[2]));

  // GET ROLL
  // Compensate pitch of gravity vector 
  Vector_Cross_Product(temp1, accel, xAxis);
  Vector_Cross_Product(temp2, xAxis, temp1);
  // Normally using x-z-plane-component/y-component of compensated gravity vector
  // roll = atan2(temp2[1], sqrt(temp2[0] * temp2[0] + temp2[2] * temp2[2]));
  // Since we compensated for pitch, x-z-plane-component equals z-component:
  roll = atan2(temp2[1], temp2[2]);

  // GET YAW
  Compass_Heading();
  yaw = MAG_Heading;

  // Init rotation matrix
  init_rotation_matrix(DCM_Matrix, yaw, pitch, roll);
}

// Apply calibration to raw sensor readings
void compensate_sensor_errors() {
  // Compensate accelerometer error
  accel[0] = (accel[0] - ACCEL_X_OFFSET) * ACCEL_X_SCALE;
  accel[1] = (accel[1] - ACCEL_Y_OFFSET) * ACCEL_Y_SCALE;
  accel[2] = (accel[2] - ACCEL_Z_OFFSET) * ACCEL_Z_SCALE;

  // Compensate magnetometer error
#if CALIBRATION__MAGN_USE_EXTENDED == true
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    magnetom_tmp[i] = magnetom[i] - magn_ellipsoid_center[i];
  Matrix_Vector_Multiply(magn_ellipsoid_transform, magnetom_tmp, magnetom);
#else
  magnetom[0] = (magnetom[0] - MAGN_X_OFFSET) * MAGN_X_SCALE;
  magnetom[1] = (magnetom[1] - MAGN_Y_OFFSET) * MAGN_Y_SCALE;
  magnetom[2] = (magnetom[2] - MAGN_Z_OFFSET) * MAGN_Z_SCALE;
#endif

  // Compensate gyroscope error
  gyro[0] -= GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_X;
  gyro[1] -= GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_Y;
  gyro[2] -= GYRO_AVERAGE_OFFSET_Z;
}

// Reset calibration session if reset_calibration_session_flag is set
void check_reset_calibration_session()
{
  // Raw sensor values have to be read already, but no error compensation applied

  // Reset this calibration session?
  if (!reset_calibration_session_flag) return;

  // Reset acc and mag calibration variables
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    accel_min[i] = accel_max[i] = accel[i];
    magnetom_min[i] = magnetom_max[i] = magnetom[i];
  }

  // Reset gyro calibration variables
  gyro_num_samples = 0;  // Reset gyro calibration averaging
  gyro_average[0] = gyro_average[1] = gyro_average[2] = 0.0f;

  reset_calibration_session_flag = false;
}

void turn_output_stream_on()
{
  output_stream_on = true;
  digitalWrite(STATUS_LED_PIN, HIGH);
}

void turn_output_stream_off()
{
  output_stream_on = false;
  digitalWrite(STATUS_LED_PIN, LOW);
}

// Blocks until another byte is available on serial port
char readChar()
{
  while (Serial.available() < 1) { 
  } // Block
  return Serial.read();
}

void setup()
{
  // Init serial output
  Serial.begin(OUTPUT__BAUD_RATE);

  // Init status LED
  pinMode (STATUS_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(STATUS_LED_PIN, LOW);

  // Init sensors
  delay(50);  // Give sensors enough time to start
  I2C_Init();
  Accel_Init();
  Magn_Init();
  Gyro_Init();

  // Read sensors, init DCM algorithm
  delay(20);  // Give sensors enough time to collect data
  reset_sensor_fusion();

  // Init output
#if (OUTPUT__HAS_RN_BLUETOOTH == true) || (OUTPUT__STARTUP_STREAM_ON == false)
  turn_output_stream_off();
#else
  turn_output_stream_on();
#endif
}

// Main loop
void loop()
{
  // Read incoming control messages
  if (Serial.available() >= 2)
  {
    if (Serial.read() == '#') // Start of new control message
    {
      int command = Serial.read(); // Commands
      if (command == 'f') // request one output _f_rame
        output_single_on = true;
      else if (command == 's') // _s_ynch request
      {
        // Read ID
        byte id[2];
        id[0] = readChar();
        id[1] = readChar();

        // Reply with synch message
        Serial.print("#SYNCH");
        Serial.write(id, 2);
        Serial.println();
      }
      else if (command == 'o') // Set _o_utput mode
      {
        char output_param = readChar();
        if (output_param == 'n')  // Calibrate _n_ext sensor
        {
          curr_calibration_sensor = (curr_calibration_sensor + 1) % 3;
          reset_calibration_session_flag = true;
        }
        else if (output_param == 't') // Output angles as _t_ext
        {
          output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_ANGLES;
          output_format = OUTPUT__FORMAT_TEXT;
        }
        else if (output_param == 'b') // Output angles in _b_inary format
        {
          output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_ANGLES;
          output_format = OUTPUT__FORMAT_BINARY;
        }
        else if (output_param == 'c') // Go to _c_alibration mode
        {
          output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_CALIBRATE_SENSORS;
          reset_calibration_session_flag = true;
        }
        else if (output_param == 's') // Output _s_ensor values
        {
          char values_param = readChar();
          char format_param = readChar();
          if (values_param == 'r')  // Output _r_aw sensor values
            output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_SENSORS_RAW;
          else if (values_param == 'c')  // Output _c_alibrated sensor values
            output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_SENSORS_CALIB;
          else if (values_param == 'b')  // Output _b_oth sensor values (raw and calibrated)
            output_mode = OUTPUT__MODE_SENSORS_BOTH;

          if (format_param == 't') // Output values as _t_text
            output_format = OUTPUT__FORMAT_TEXT;
          else if (format_param == 'b') // Output values in _b_inary format
            output_format = OUTPUT__FORMAT_BINARY;
        }
        else if (output_param == '0') // Disable continuous streaming output
        {
          turn_output_stream_off();
          reset_calibration_session_flag = true;
        }
        else if (output_param == '1') // Enable continuous streaming output
        {
          reset_calibration_session_flag = true;
          turn_output_stream_on();
        }
        else if (output_param == 'e') // _e_rror output settings
        {
          char error_param = readChar();
          if (error_param == '0') output_errors = false;
          else if (error_param == '1') output_errors = true;
          else if (error_param == 'c') // get error count
          {
            Serial.print("#AMG-ERR:");
            Serial.print(num_accel_errors); 
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(num_magn_errors); 
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.println(num_gyro_errors);
          }
        }
      }
#if OUTPUT__HAS_RN_BLUETOOTH == true
      // Read messages from bluetooth module
      // For this to work, the connect/disconnect message prefix of the module has to be set to "#".
      else if (command == 'C') // Bluetooth "#CONNECT" message (does the same as "#o1")
        turn_output_stream_on();
      else if (command == 'D') // Bluetooth "#DISCONNECT" message (does the same as "#o0")
        turn_output_stream_off();
#endif // OUTPUT__HAS_RN_BLUETOOTH == true
    }
    else
    { 
    } // Skip character
  }

  // Time to read the sensors again?
  if((millis() - timestamp) >= OUTPUT__DATA_INTERVAL)
  {
    timestamp_old = timestamp;
    timestamp = millis();
    if (timestamp > timestamp_old)
      G_Dt = (float) (timestamp - timestamp_old) / 1000.0f; // Real time of loop run. We use this on the DCM algorithm (gyro integration time)
    else G_Dt = 0;

    // Update sensor readings
    read_sensors();

    if (output_mode == OUTPUT__MODE_CALIBRATE_SENSORS)  // We're in calibration mode
    {
      check_reset_calibration_session();  // Check if this session needs a reset
      if (output_stream_on || output_single_on) output_calibration(curr_calibration_sensor);
    }
    else if (output_mode == OUTPUT__MODE_ANGLES)  // Output angles
    {
      // Apply sensor calibration
      compensate_sensor_errors();

      // Run DCM algorithm
      Compass_Heading(); // Calculate magnetic heading
      Matrix_update();
      Normalize();
      Drift_correction();
      Euler_angles();

      if (output_stream_on || output_single_on) output_angles();
    }
    else  // Output sensor values
    {      
      if (output_stream_on || output_single_on) output_sensors();
    }

    output_single_on = false;

#if DEBUG__PRINT_LOOP_TIME == true
    Serial.print("loop time (ms) = ");
    Serial.println(millis() - timestamp);
#endif
  }
#if DEBUG__PRINT_LOOP_TIME == true
  else
  {
    Serial.println("waiting...");
  }
#endif
}
```

And well, the code only includes the library  which is for I2C communication, but there are 5 more files (.ino which is simply an .cpp) that have few functions being declared.

By just simply trying to compile the code, the following error is given:

```
Final_arduino_code.ino: In function ‘void read_sensors()’:
Final_arduino_code:427: error: ‘Read_Gyro’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:428: error: ‘Read_Accel’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:429: error: ‘Read_Magn’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code.ino: In function ‘void reset_sensor_fusion()’:
Final_arduino_code:450: error: ‘Vector_Cross_Product’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:458: error: ‘Compass_Heading’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:462: error: ‘init_rotation_matrix’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code.ino: In function ‘void compensate_sensor_errors()’:
Final_arduino_code:476: error: ‘Matrix_Vector_Multiply’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code.ino: In function ‘void setup()’:
Final_arduino_code:541: error: ‘I2C_Init’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:542: error: ‘Accel_Init’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:543: error: ‘Magn_Init’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:544: error: ‘Gyro_Init’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
Final_arduino_code:675: error: ‘output_calibration’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:683: error: ‘Compass_Heading’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:684: error: ‘Matrix_update’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:685: error: ‘Normalize’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:686: error: ‘Drift_correction’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:687: error: ‘Euler_angles’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:689: error: ‘output_angles’ was not declared in this scope
Final_arduino_code:693: error: ‘output_sensors’ was not declared in this scope
```

Well, most of those functions have being declared in the other files in the same folder of the this main code, BUT, I have tried making a header (.h) to each of the files, just declaring the functions, it didn't work, I have tried including the files as they are, didn't work, tried to change them to .cpp and including, didn't work.

I posted as an issue to both of the github pages but still got no answer.

Please help me to fix these errors, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original project owner "Ahmet YILDIRIM" replied to my problem and helped me to compile the project, this was his answer:

> You know when you try opening an INO file, Arduino IDE asks you if you
>   would like to create a new folder for that specific file.
>
> If you click yes, it seperates that file into a new folder.
>
> If I remember correctly you should either press “No” then add other
>   files as new tabs. If you click “Yes”, then add other files into new
>   created folder and then open them all in new tabs.
>
> I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

> but there are 5 more files (.ino which is simply an .cpp)

It is not that simple, they are *not* .cpp files.  They are supposed to be built with the `Ino` toolkit, the project's home page [is here](http://inotool.org/).  Judging from the compiler errors you get, you are not using this toolkit.

The core part that's missing are the .h files that the compiler normally needs to understand what functions like Read_Gyro() look like.  Currently the projects you listed have no .h file and no corresponding #include directives.  Not actually sure how Ino works but I'd guess it acts like a preprocessor that merges the .ino files into one big ball of source code before letting the compiler lose on it.

Using the toolkit is strongly recommended to get ahead and avoid substantial changes.

Comment: Well, its a great though, although the github project have a tutorial in which it says that you only have to download arduino software, no ino compile, check it out here: https://github.com/ptrbrtz/razor-9dof-ahrs/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: If you see files with the .ino file extension then you believe your eyes, not an out-of-date tutorial.  If you don't believe your eyes then you believe the compiler.  If you don't believe the compiler then you believe an SO user.  If you don't believe an SO user then you'll need to learn what you are doing from the ground up instead of trying to use somebody else's source code.

Comment: Man, I didn't want to use somebody else source code, its just that accelerometer are so full of s*** they are very annoying piece of hardware to use, so many software treatment to do, I just wanted to see it work as I want with any code, thats the best I found =/. But i'm currently downloading linux to try your way, once I get it installed i'll feedback here. So far thanks for the answer, soon i'll reply

Answer (score 1):

As I do not have enough reputation, I'll tell how the Guilherme Garcia da Rosa's answer put me on the right direction.

Unfortunately his contribution appears to be no longer valid with Arduino IDE 1.6.5

I managed to open the project this way :

1- Close Arduino IDE first

2- Create a directory named Final_arduino_code (maybe case sensitive)

3- Open Arduino IDE, and the sketch Final_arduino_code.ino

The IDE will automatically load all files.

The program uploaded successfully for me this way.